StoreKit 2: .subscriptionStatusTask lag and how to display a ProgressView in the interim?
I am currently using .subscriptionStatusTask on the main view for my app. Everything seems to be working pretty well so far with my testing in Xcode. However, when I popped this over to TestFlight, I notice that I'm getting some "lag" between once I "buy" a subscription and when .subscriptionStatusTask kicks off after it notices the change. In other words, it takes a few seconds before my app knows that it's the "Pro" version and not the initial non-subscription version (I set a published variable indicating pro or not pro). So my questions are:

Is this normal behavior? Should there be a bit of a lag?
Should I just set my published var to true as soon as a successful purchase happens? Note: I'm using .manageSubscriptionSheet; so, there doesn't seem to be a way to set this variable if the user resubscribes or upgrades their subscription from there.
Is there a way to somehow set a ProgressView while .subscriptionStatusTask is loading/thinking? Since it's a modifier and I'm setting the published "pro" var within the closure, I can't seem to actually get this to work properly. I tried setting a progress view status type flag to true when .subscriptionStatusTask kicks off but I can't seem to find a way to properly reset the flag so that it knows that it's finished and the progress view goes away.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

So, I'm still testing but it seems that async/await may be the answer here. Thoughts?

I decided to use async/await and call two functions... one to do majority of the work to check which subscription is active (or none) and the other to reset the flag for the ProgressView. I used a .overlay on my main view for when the ProgressView is active with frame as maxWidth/maxHeight of .infinity and the background .white.opacity(0.25). For now, this seems to work for me. Given my logic, I may also have to consider how things work if the user doesn't have a network connection and wants to work offline. However, that's for another post if I run into trouble. I still don't really know why there's such a lag with .subscriptionStatusTask but I thought I'd post what I did in case anyone else is trying to find a work-around for their code.
